# RDD filter with other function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I know how to filter a RDD like `val y = rdd.filter(e => e%2==0)`, but I do not know how to combine filter with other function like `Row`.

In `val rst = rdd.map(ab => Row(ab.a, ab.b))`, I want to filter out `ab.b > 0`, but I tried put filter at multiple place and they do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the "out" part in "filter out": do you want to keep those entries, or do you want to get rid of them? If you want to *drop* all entries with `ab.b > 0`, then you need

```
val rst = rdd.filterNot(_.b > 0).map(ab => Row(ab.a, ab.b))
```

If you want to *retain* only the entries with `ab.b > 0`, then try

```
val rst = rdd.filter(_.b > 0).map(ab => Row(ab.a, ab.b))
```

The underscore `_` is simply the shorter form of

```
val rst = rdd.filter(ab => ab.b > 0).map(ab => Row(ab.a, ab.b))
```